# Using overbrace in xymatrix

Tags: xy-pic

My TeX code is not compiling correctly (the overbrace is causing the error). How I can fix my file?

Here's what I have:

```
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{mathrsfs}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{stackrel} 
 \usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy} 
 \usepackage{multicol} 
 \usepackage{mathtools}


 \begin{document}


 \[
 \xymatrix@-1pc{
 \stackrel{1}{\bullet} \ar[rr] & & \bullet & \overbrace{\cdots}^{N} & \bullet \ar[rr] & & \stackrel{k}{\bullet} \\ 
 }
 \] 



 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an extra pair of braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackrel} 
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy} 
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix@-1pc{
 \stackrel{1}{\bullet} \ar[rr] & & \bullet & {\overbrace{\cdots}^{N}} & \bullet \ar[rr] & & \stackrel{k}{\bullet} \\ 
}
\] 

 \end{document}
```

[image]

In my example I  didn't load packages that were not needed for the given code. Since you load `mathtools`, there's no need to load `amsmath`.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know much about which packages are necessary when texing so for the time-being, I just include them all. And yes, this answer will be accepted as the answer.